# PyAutoGUI - LocateAllOnScreen - Why is confidence not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am trying to make an aimbot for [diep](https://diep.io). I am trying to locate all enemies on the screen, but with 1 confidence it returns `None` and with 0.9999 confidence it returns every single position on the screen.

I am using PyCharm, and when I run the code, it returns every location on the screen even though there isn't anything red. Then when I set confidence to 1, it doesn't even return locations that are red.

I have even tried opening the file and seeing if it could find the color. It didn't work, same results.

**My Code**

```py
# https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html
from pyautogui import locateAllOnScreen, moveTo

while True:
    """
    try:
        coords = list(locateAllOnScreen('enemycolordiep.png'))
    except 'ImageNotFoundException':
        coords = []
    """

    coords = locateAllOnScreen('enemycolordiep.png', confidence=X)
    if coords is None:
        coords = []

    else:
        coords = list(coords)

    print(coords)

    for coord in coords:
        centerCoord = (coord[0] + (coord[2] / 2), coord[1] + (coord[3] / 2))
        print(centerCoord)
        # moveTo(centerCoord[0], centerCoord[1], duration=0)
```

I expected to get the red locations on the screen, but this is not working. I have `pyautogui`, `pyobjc-core`, `pyobjc-framework-quartz`, `Pillow`, `opencv-python`, and a bunch of other stuff that those packages were dependent on. I am using MacOS Mojave. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Using pillow: check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56636259/8928024) to see how you test for color value of a particular pixel. BTW.. update your question to include the pillow code you use. Can be posted as second scritp in your question termed "alternative" or something.

Comment: How will RGB color matching help with image location?

Comment: ... you stated "locations that are red" are more or less enemies.  In WoW its a circled shield in color yellow so scan for those shapes in your screen output or use X-axis histogram score with Y as intensity. If enemies available location pixels are Red = 255 and if not pixel Red = 0. And voila... you got your enemies separated from the civilians. For specific circle, rectangle or square detection try openCV (cv2) in all other cases histrogram with small region (y1,y2; x1,x2) will work.

Comment: But doesn't PyAutoGUI use OpenCV in background? I installed it and pillow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating/installing openCV.

See this answer to similar a question: [Documentation says to use a confidence parameter, but it throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832850/documentation-says-to-use-a-confidence-parameter-but-it-throws-an-error)