# Is RGB taken from ImageGrab.grab().load() is in array or string

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image, pixel

I am making a bot in python. I want to compare the colors of a particular pixel with another color which is (83, 83, 83).

I tried comparing with a string with single and double quotes. It didn't work so I thought that it could be an array.

This is my code of the bot

```py
import pyautogui as py
from PIL import ImageGrab


def pressspace():
    py.keyDown('space')
    py.keyUp('space')

def jump():
    px=ImageGrab.grab().load()
    color=px[207,445]

    if color=='(83, 83, 83)':




        pressspace()

while True:
    jump()
```

It just didn't work and didn't press the space. I have imported all dependencies  also. Please Help and tell that is it an array and if yes, than how to compare.(Note: rest time the color is (247, 247, 247))

Comment: ...and `ImageGrab` is what exactly? Complete your code to working example. (playing "dumb' here ;p)

Comment: ImageGrab is from ```from PIL import ImageGrab```

Comment: ..thats what I said "playing dumb"... question wasn't currated correctly by other users. Cheer for the mod.

Comment: it returns an instance of a pixel image class. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.load

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html#pixelaccess

Comment: When I print it, it gives me '(83, 83, 83)' excluding quotes

Comment: You can check it type with `type(color)`...

Comment: where should I put it?

Comment: ...hmmm the presspace is adding actual whitespaces in the script at the spot I place the mousecursor.... I guess that's not what you're looking for...

Comment: @ZF007 sorry for late reply, The pressspace that you are getting is for another purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind you didn't state what 'py' in pressspace() is and does for your code snippet.

```
import sys, time
from PIL import ImageGrab


def pressspace():
    py.keyDown('space')
    py.keyUp('space')

def jump():
    px=ImageGrab.grab().load()
    color=px[207,445]
    c1, c2, c3 = color     # just a thought: if included you can compare and print each  
                           # of them to see if they fit a certain value of your liking.

    if color==(83, 83, 83):
        print ('1 - type: ', type(color))
    else:
        print ('2 - type: ', type(color))

    print (color)  # just to print always the color

    time.sleep(1)   # pause it for one second to prevent SPAM in the output.

    # pressspace()

while True:
    jump()
    sys.stdout.flush()  # forces to print directly the result from within an editor if used.
```

In my case its an `<class 'tuple'>`

Comment: If it's a tuple, why are you comparing to a string?

Comment: saw OP did that... did fix that ;-)

Comment: Just a thought: added c1,c2,c3 to show you that you actually can check from there each individual pixel value if you want to do that. Didn't include the actual selection code but you get the picture ;p

Comment: Sorry, but I now know the complete meaning of your answer