# Documentation says to use a confidence parameter, but it throws an error

Tags: python, pyautogui

Edit to include code snippet.

I am developing an app with pyautogui. I want to match a region on the desktop and click it. Calling the locateOnscreen function, I pass the filename containing the image to match, along with a confidence parameter, which throws an error.

```
import pyautogui as pag
button_login = pag.locateOnScreen("button_login.png", confidence=0.7)

File ".\test.py", line 23, in <module>
button_login = pag.locateOnScreen("button_login.png", confidence=0.7)
...
TypeError: _locateAll_python() got an unexpected keyword argument 'confidence'
```

Installed version is 0.9.47. The docs refer to version 1.0.0. I can't find this version anywhere including pypi and github.

Comment: could you also pls show a little bit of your code?

Comment: updated to include snippet

Answer (score 14):

This happens because the function `locateOnScreen` can reach two different functions ([source code](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L497)):

- `_locateAll_opencv` if cv2 / OpenCV is installed
- `_locateAll_python` if cv2 / OpenCV cannot be found or if you are using python3 with a version of cv2 inferior to 3

And `_locateAll_python` doesn't handle the `confidence` parameter.

So you can try to install/update OpenCV if you need this feature : https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Or if you have python 2 & 3 on your system:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This worked for me too. using `pip3`.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install opencv-python`

pyautogui uses OpenCV in the back end to calculate confidence, and therefore it needs to be installed in Python before you can use the Confidence argument. Good luck.

Comment: Hi! This seems to be what the other answer that's already been there for a while recommends. Could you maybe edit your answer to clarify how your answer is different?