# PyAutoGui not identifying installed OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

I'm trying to use `pyautogui` to find image in my screen, with `confidence` params set.
But it's asking me to install OpenCV, since I've already have `opencv-python` installed.

My code is like this:

```
import pyautogui
location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('123.png', confidence=1)
```

The full error message:

```
    raise NotImplementedError('The confidence keyword argument is only available if OpenCV is installed.')
NotImplementedError: The confidence keyword argument is only available if OpenCV is installed.
```

My stack is:

- Virtual Env
- Python 3
- Mac OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Documentation says to use a confidence parameter, but it throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832850/documentation-says-to-use-a-confidence-parameter-but-it-throws-an-error)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that I had `opencv-python` installed but I didn't have `opencv` installed.

Comment: For other folks' info, at least as of version 4.8.1.78, OpenCV binaries are installed along with the opencv-python package.

Answer (score 0):

Test alone the OpenCV library installation with something like this:

```
import cv2
```

If you are using Windows and the following error appears

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Try to install Windows "Media Feature Pack". On Windows 11 go to **Settings>Apps>Optional features** click the **Add an optional feature** button and search "Media Feature Pack". Once installed don't forget to reboot.

*This worked for me using Windows 11 Pro N 22H2 (non activated) on an x64 AMD Rayzen 7. Installing the "Media Feature Pack" also fixed my problems with the webcam.*